# I want to display the output with full string

Tags: powershell, powercli

```
Connect-VIServer XXXX

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Result=@()
$vms = Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'XXX*'}
try{
 ForEach ($v in $vms)
  {
   foreach ($d in $v.ExtensionData.Guest.Disk)
    {
    $usedSpace = $d.Capacity - $d.FreeSpace
    $percentUsed =  [math]::Round(($usedSpace / $d.Capacity) * 100)

    $List = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        SERVER_NAME = $v.Name | Out-String
            "Total_Capacity(GB)" = [math]::round([int]($d.Capacity/1GB), 1)
            "Free_Space(GB)" = [math]::round([int]($d.FreeSpace/1GB), 1)
            PercentFull = "$percentUsed%"
                        }
                #Write-Host "$ErrorList"
            $Result+=$List
    }
  }
}
catch [Exception]
{
write-host "OD-VM-Monitor: $v : FATAL SCRIPT ERROR" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

I have executed the above script. but while trying to display the result, it is showing with dot like below . I tried the below two.

```
$Result | Select-Object SERVER_NAME, 'Total_Capacity(GB)', 'Free_Space(GB)', PercentFull | Out-String -Width 4096 | ft -auto
$Result | Select-Object SERVER_NAME, 'Total_Capacity(GB)', 'Free_Space(GB)', PercentFull | Format-Table -AutoSize

SERVER_NAME     Total_Capacity(GB) Free_Space(GB) PercentFull
-----------     ------------------ -------------- -----------
XXXXXXX...                200            113 43%
XXXXXXX...                150             50 67%
XXXXXXX...                150             31 79%
XXXXXXX...                100             32 68%
XXXXXXX...                500             87 83%
XXXXXXX...                100             43 57%
XXXXXXX...                100             36 64%
XXXXXXX...                150             37 75%
```

Any idea how to get rid out of the dots.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the strings are too wide for your screen (console windows).
Try a format-list instead of format-table to confirm that data is not ruined.

This is a guide to Change the size both programmatically and through the GUI: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/12/04/how-can-i-expand-the-width-of-the-windows-powershell-console/

Comment: changing the window size is not helping here.
any way to write the whole output in a file without dots?

Comment: Writing to a file can be done with export-csv or maybe out-file... that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Format-Table can take a [hash table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692794.aspx) specifying column widths.